# What do I do when dist upgrade to 12.04 was interrupted in install-stage by  the system being  powered off?

Tags: data-recovery, release-upgrade

How do I check system state when dist upgrade was interrupted during install stage by power-off? I just run `dpkg -l | grep -v "^ii"` to ensure that I have no broken packages installed. At the first glance everything works but I doubt that as the upgrade dialog was just before crash at 70% of estimated install-work (cleaning and removing wasn't even done too). What should I do next? Reinstall every package?

**Background:**

I just started to upgrade to 12.04 and wile installing packages the screen went blank (but with visible mouse pointer). I was still able to got to a console by CTRL+ALT+F1 and was still able to log in. Although I couldn't see any process working on dist upgrade which made me very curious, as it was still more than 1h of estimated work to do. I rebooted and System was behaving very slow. After deleting some folders like .gconf, .local, .config, etc.. login was working flawlessly again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run a `apt-get install -f`?

Comment: I just put it in command line and it returned without any error to correct.

Comment: I'm far from being an expert on the Ubuntu upgrade process, but IMHO it looks as if you should be fine. But others are very welcome to correct me.